# Using Event Filter in Task Scheduler looking for specific keywords

Tags: windows, task-scheduler, eventviewer

I hope you can help, sometimes a backup task will fail, usually a transient VSS error, and re-running the backup will normally complete successfully.  What I am trying to do is use the event filter within Task Schdeuler to trigger the backup to restart.  I've had no problem doing this from just targeting the EventID (5635) but I have a number of backup jobs running so I need to be more specific which is where I'm coming up against a brick wall.

The XML event data looks like this:

```
<EventData>
<Data>
Backup job Server Backup 1 completed with warnings. Major Warning: One or more Hyper-V guests have reported errors that could result in an incomplete backup. Check each guest's event log and review any errors reported. Major Warning: Volume Shadow Copy Error 0x800423f4 - writer error: non retryable Destination: Local hard drive Bytes: 7191744309979 Start time: 01/01/2021 22:00:02 End time: 01/01/2021 22:12:25 Duration: 00:12:23.0745879 Job Execution ID: 1.679
</Data> 
</EventData>
```

I am trying to get the event filter to pick up on the "Server backup 1" text and I'm using the following query:

```
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="Application">
<Select Path="Application">*[System[Provider[@Name='BackupAssist'] and (Level=3) and (EventID=5635) and *[EventData[Data[1]='Server Backup 1']]]]</Select>
</Query>
</QueryList>
```

However this doesn't trigger when the event is recorded.  I am suspecting it's a wildcard string issue but I am not sure.

Any help gratefully received
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not implemented, [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/consuming-events?redirectedfrom=MSDN#xpath-10-limitations) shows you the limitations and lists the three functions that you can use:

> [...]
> Node Tests: Only node names and NCName tests are supported. The "*" character, which
> selects any character, is supported.
> [...]
>
> The position function, and its shorthand array reference, is supported (on leaf nodes only).
> The Band function is supported. The function performs a bitwise AND for two integer number arguments. If the result of the bitwise AND is nonzero, the function evaluates to true; otherwise, the function evaluates to false.
> The timediff function is supported.[...]

You can create a scheduled task with the Event ID trigger to start a remediation script in which you can perform additional verification to determine if the script should proceed further.

Comment: Thanks for that, and I hadn't thought of triggering another script to do the query...so thanks again.